# How to expand variables using previously defined variables inside a file

Tags: bash

I have a property file having multiple key value pairs. Some of the values uses previously defined keys. Following is the sample

```
  xpath=abc/temp.txt
  fullpath=$HOME/$xpath
  ...
```

I want to parse this file line by line and print the lines along with resolving env variables like $HOME as well as earlier defined variables like $xpath

The expected output is

```
  xpath=abc/temp.txt
  fullpath=tempuser/abc/temp.txt
  ...
```

How do I expand the variables in this way in a bash script

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? It feels like you're asking for a step in a solution that might not be the best for the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse line by line and interpret the variables, You maybe want to use the `eval` for evaluating the **String**, like:

```
  while IFS='=' read -r key value
  do
    key=$(echo $key | tr '.' '_')
    if [[ ! -z $key ]]
    then
        v=`eval "echo ${value}"`
        eval "${key}='${v}'"
        echo "${key}=${v}"
    fi
  done < "my.properties"
```

In the above code snippet, use the `eval` with `echo` to interpret the `variables`.

Comment: I want the output to be printed on the terminal. Can you add the printf so that I'll get the expected output as stated in the question.

Comment: Hi @Vivek, for the output, you can use `echo "${key}=${v}"` for this.

Comment: Thanks. One last thing - It is skipping the last line

Answer (score 0):

Since the assignments are valid bash, `source settings.env` suffices to evaluate them. However, you also want to print the assignments, so more trickery required:

```
PS4="\000" source <(echo 'set -x'; cat settings.env; echo '{ set +x; } 2>/dev/null')
```

This trick uses the bash debugging facility of `set -x` to print the output of each assignment as it's performed. In words:

- `PS4="\000"` removes the debugging prompt, which by default is `+`
- `<()` creates a new file, by the pipeline contained within the parentheses
- `set -x` enables debugging
- `cat settings.env` inserts your settings
- `{ set +x; } 2>dev/null` disables debugging, without outputting it doing so

Comment: Thanks. But i want to print the output (the whole file) not just evaluate the variables

Comment: I missed that requirement. Answer edited accordingly.